# Using multiple two column values to access database information

Tags: magento, parameters

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and need to access information within my database. I have achieved this by

```
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $prefs = Mage::getModel('prefs/prefs')->setCurPage(1)
                                          ->setPageSize(1);
    $prefs->load($params['id']);
    $data = $prefs->getData();
```

But this is only selecting data by using a single column as a reference within my table and I need to use two columns to get a unique value.

How do I select those two columns and apply those values as the parameter required in the address bar?

In my reseearch I have looked at [this](http://dltr.org/blog/magento/418/Magento-get-url-with-or-without-parameters) and applied _query, but couldn't work out how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to query like this check following code and change as per your requirement

```
$Model =Mage::getModel('prefs/prefs')->getCollection();
$Model->addFieldToFilter('first_column',array('eq'=>'your_id'))
      ->addFieldToFilter('Second_column',array('eq'=>'Your_filter_data'));
$finalData = $Model->getData();
```